# asp.net mvc 4 websecurity two step login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, membership-provider, simplemembership

i have created asp.net mvc 4 internet app. 
As you know, there is standard method of authorization there through websecurity.login
inside login action AccountController

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
```

After WebSecurity.Login, if username and password are correct user become logged.
But i want 2 step login. So after WebSecurity.Login, if if username and password are correct, user goes to another page where he/she must enter special code and only after this (if code correct) user become logged.
So The question can i do this, by rewrite websecurity class, without creating custom membership provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The System.Web.Security namespace has a `Membership` class that contains a [`ValidateUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.validateuser.aspx) method that validates without logging the user in. You can use that to then redirect to the second step page:

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
{
    // redirect to step 2...
}
```

Keep in mind that `Membership` will refer to the default membership provider registered in the `web.config`, which I believe looks like this in your case:

```
<membership defaultProvider="simple">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="simple" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
    </providers>
</membership>
```

Comment: Hi, i've checked  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg547905(v=VS.99).aspx, there is no method  ValidateUser in Websecurity class.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the Web.Security namespace... :) I have updated the answer.